# EmberJS Query Parameters By Default

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a way for the URL to get updated with a default query param if a user navigates to the link by default?

For example, I have:

```
Ember.Controller.extend({

  queryParams: [
    'us_date',
    'us_users',
  ],

  us_date: 365,
  us_users: null,

})
```

I want the url to have

```
url_here/?us_date=365
```

upon visiting the controller for

```
url_here
```

I check the value of the query param and it is `365` once I enter the controller but the URL is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

In the route.  Check the params.  If none are set, transition to the route w/ the param you want.  If you expect it to be displayed in the URL, don't set its default value in the controller.